# Convergent Bounded Linear Maps

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm not sure how to show that the composition of two convergent bounded linear maps converges to the composition of their limits. I've shown that the composition of bounded linear maps is a bounded linear map, but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $T_n \rightarrow T$ and $U_n\rightarrow U$ are the convergent sequences of bounded linear maps. For any $x$,
\begin{align}
\|UTx - U_nT_nx\| &\leq \|(U - U_n)Tx\| + \|U_n(Tx - T_nx)\| \\
&\leq \|U-U_n\|\|Tx\| + \|U_n\|\|T-T_n\|\|x\|.
\end{align}
Take the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$, the RHS tends to $0$.